# web3j - Unable to determine sync status of node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I have setup a private ethereum node in my laptop using below command.

> geth --datadir=./chaindata/ init ./genesis.json
>
> geth --datadir=./chaindata/ --rpc console

The chainId in genesis.json is set to 10 to avoid connecting to main ethereum network. web3j java library is used to send some ether to another account.

```
   Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());  
    log.info("Connected to Ethereum client version: "
            + web3j.web3ClientVersion().send().getWeb3ClientVersion());

    Credentials credentials =
            WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
                    "password",
                    "path-to-wallet-file");

    log.info("Sending 1 Wei ("
            + Convert.fromWei("1", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toPlainString() + " Ether)");
    TransactionReceipt transferReceipt = Transfer.sendFunds(
                web3j, credentials,
                "to-account",  
                BigDecimal.ONE, Convert.Unit.WEI)  // 1 wei = 10^-18 Ether
                .sendAsync().get();
```

What is the root cause for the below exception ?

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.web3j.ens.EnsResolutionException: Unable to determine sync status of node
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to having an invalid wallet address in to-account parameter in sendFunds() method.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the [Class EnsResolver](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/ens/EnsResolver.java) as shown above "org.web3j.ens.EnsResolutionException" and it is saying that the node you are connected to **does not have a Public Resolver installed** in that could provide an access to the API.

"Your node does not Provide an access to a **valid public resolver** in order to access other API methods."

Before using the command you should check if there is a support for ENS on the node you are connected, using the command **Check Interface Support**:
Check this [link](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/publicresolver#check-interface-support).

"Callers must not assume that a domain uses the current version of the public resolver, or that all of the methods described here are present. To check if a resolver supports a feature, see **Check Interface Support**."

***So to sum up your node does not have one Public Resolver in it, so it can not provide the ENS Resolver method for you.***

[Edit] As you said in your post that you have setup a private node, you should try a public well known node. It may help you the: [**Infura**](https://infura.io/) nodes (endpoints).

If you want to follow a nice TUTORIAL try this [link](https://kauri.io/ens-beginners-guide/e7f098b57fd24afe9b70506517dd5a63/a).

Also check out this [link](https://github.com/AlphaWallet/alpha-wallet-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alphawallet/app/util/EnsResolver.java).